# How to add new elements to the html in the code behind c#, dynamically

Tags: c#, webforms, code-behind

I have this code, but I can't see nothing in the view, the idea is return data from database then display in the new elements, how can show the new elements?

```
private void llenarRequisitos()
{
    int tipoVisado = int.Parse(droplistTipoVisado.SelectedItem.Value);
    int tipoTramite = int.Parse(droplistTipoTramite.SelectedItem.Value);

    _servicio7 = _servicio7 ?? new Servicio<CatalogoRequisito>();
    var lista = _servicio7.TraerTodoEspecificoPor(new Query<CatalogoRequisito> { Where = x => x.TipoVisado == tipoVisado && x.TipoTramite == tipoTramite && x.Estado==true });

    MessageBox.Show(lista.Count.ToString());

    for(int i=0; i < lista.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hola");

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
        chk.ID = "chk" + i;

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
        lbl.ID = "labelRequisito" + i;
        lbl.Text = lista[i].Descripcion+"("+lista[i].Caracter+")";

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload file = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload();
        file.ID = "file" + i;

        this.requisitos.Controls.Add(chk);
        this.requisitos.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.requisitos.Controls.Add(file);
    }
}
```

```
<div id="requisitos" runat="server" class="grid5">
</div>
```

Comment: What event handler calls this code?

Comment: DropDownList, OnTextChanged, not is in the page load

Comment: the idea idea is when a user select something in the dropdownlist i need to show some elements dynamically

Comment: You are sure `lista > 0`?

Comment: What is `MessageBox.Show`? Is this web forms?